# Adding extra information to ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

So I guess this question doesn't just pertain to `ImageView` but any control really.

In my app I'm listing all .mp3 files in a folder and create an `ImageView` for each of them which is added to my form. These `ImageViews` are basically just icons which, when clicked on, will trigger the sound clip being played.

What would be the best way to remember the filename of the .mp3 that resulted in the `ImageView` being created so that I can get hold of that file again in the `OnClick()` handler of the `ImageView`?

Here's how the ImageViews are created:

```
File[] files = myPath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
    }
});
for (File file : files)
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // Here I would like to reference file.getAbsolutePath() which
            // I obviously can't so I need to find some way of "remembering"
            // it for this particular ImageView
        }
    });
    myLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.setTag()?` method which accepts an Object.

Try  this:

```
 imageView.setTag(file);
```

Link to docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this? Just declare the `file` variable as `final`, then you will be able to access this from the `OnClickListener`.

```
for (final File file : files)
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't realise you could use the final modifier in a `for` statement. It's a perfect and elegant solution for what I'm trying to achieve here but I'm accepting the .setTag() answer as it is more versatile. Thanks though. I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without setTag() also like this way

```
for (File file : files)
{
    final File myFile = file;
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
             myFile.getgetAbsolutePath();

            // Here I would like to reference file.getAbsolutePath() which
            // I obviously can't so I need to find some way of "remembering"
            // it for this particular ImageView
        }
    });
    myLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```